# How to print line of a file after match an exact string pattern with python?

Tags: python

I have a list

```
list = ['plutino?','res 2:11','Uranus L4','res 9:19','damocloid','cubewano?','plutino']
```

I want to search every element from the list in a file with the next format and print the line after match

```
1995QY9      |  1995_QY9     | plutino       |  32929  |                |    39.445  |   0.260  | 29.193    |    49.696   |    4.8   |     66  | #   0.400   |  1.21 BR-U   | ?
1997CU29     |  1997_CU29    | cubewano      |  33001  |                |    43.534  |   0.039  | 41.815    |    45.253   |    1.5   |    243  |             |  1.82 RR     | 
1998BU48     |  1998_BU48    | Centaur       |  33128  |                |    33.363  |   0.381  | 20.647    |    46.078   |   14.2   |    213  | #   0.052   |  1.59 RR     | ?
1998VG44     |  1998_VG44    | plutino       |  33340  |                |    39.170  |   0.250  | 29.367    |    48.974   |    3.0   |    398  | #   0.028   |  1.51 IR     | 
1998SN165    |  1998_SN165   | inner classic |  35671  |                |    37.742  |   0.041  | 36.189    |    39.295   |    4.6   |    393  | #   0.060   |  1.13 BB     | 
2000VU2      |  2000_VU2     | unusual       |  37117  | Narcissus      |     6.878  |   0.554  |  3.071    |    10.685   |   13.8   |     11  | #   0.088   |              | 
1999HX11     |  1999_HX11    | plutino?      |  38083  | Rhadamanthus   |    39.220  |   0.151  | 33.295    |    45.144   |   12.7   |    168  |             |  1.18 BR     | 
1999HB12     |  1999_HB12    | res 2:5       |  38084  |                |    56.376  |   0.422  | 32.566    |    80.187   |   13.1   |    176  |             |  1.39 BR-IR  |
```

I am using the next code to do that

```
for i in list:
with open("tnolist.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(i, line):
            print(line)
```

The code works fine for all element, except for **plutino**. When the variable **i** is **plutino** the code prints lines for **plutino** and for **plutino?**.

Comment: The `?` in the string is making an issue. You need a mechanism to make an exact match for that string. You can do

`ind = i.index('?') ;  i = i[:ind] + "\\" + i[ind:]` 

to append `\\` in the string so that it will take ``?` as an actual character in your search.

Comment: Please, do not name list objects as `list`!

Comment: Do you actually re-open the file for each world in the `list`?

Comment: Finally, how can this code "work fine" when it **does not** _"print the line **after** match"_?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because **plutino** is a substring of **plutino?**, so the regex parser matches the first part of **plutino?** and returns a non-falsey answer. Without a whole lot of additional work, you should be able to fix the problem with `re.search(i, line+r'\s')`, which says that you need to have a whitespace character after the phrase you're searching. As the file gets longer and more complicated, you might have more such exceptions to make the regex behave as desired.

**Update:** I also like [visual regex editors](http://myregexp.com/) for reasons like this. They make it easy to see what matches and what doesn't.

Another option would be something like `i==line.split('|')[2].strip()` which extracts the portion of your file you seem to care about. The `.strip()` method can become inefficient on long lines, but this might fit your use case.